# codeigniter static pages tutorial

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm getting into frameworks and I'm using CI so i can more familiar with OOP. In the static pages tutorial in the pages controller I am told to copy this code

```
<?php   

class Pages extends CI_Controller {

    public function view($page = 'home') {

        if (!file_exists(APPPATH . '/views/pages' . $page . '.php')) {

            // we dont have a page for that!
            show_404();
        }

        $data['title'] = ucfirst($page); //Capitilize the first letter

        $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('pages/' . $page, $data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer', $data);
    }
}

?>
```

in the **if statement** its blocking the pages I'm trying to load such as **about.php and index.php**

when I remove the `!` in the if statement I'm able to render the **about.php and index.php** which is good, I'm able to load my pages according to the tutorial, but if I type in something random like **asdasd.php** i don't get the 404 error I get an **AN ERROR WAS ENCOUNTERED Unable to load the requested file: pages/asdasd.php**

How can i go about fixing this issue, having CI display the 404 when the file isn't there.

Thanks

Comment: I think you need to add a `/` (slash) just after `/pages` in `APPPATH . '/views/pages' . $page . '.php'`. Try that and let me know if it worked.

Comment: @GustavoStraube LMFAO!!! wow thakns man, post the answer and its all yours!! this was giving me headaches... i thought it was a logic issue but everything still wasn't making sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the issue is in the path in your `file_exists` call.

You need to add a `/` (slash) just after `/pages` in the following line:

```
if (!file_exists(APPPATH . '/views/pages' . $page . '.php')) {
```